# php artisan make:controller Command not working in Laravel 5.3 Moduler App

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am working on a Module App in Laravel 5.3. I have setup module and It is working nice. My App directory structure is as below:

```
App
    |
    |_Http
    |
    |_Modules
       |_SMS
          |_Controllers
          |_Models
          |_Views
```

My question is, how I can make a controller in Modules/SMS/Controller folder from command line? I tried `"php artisan make:controller App/Modules/SMS/Controller/Api/V1/UserController"`. But controller create in Http/Controller/Api/V1 directory. That is default Controller Directory. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the path in which you have to create the controller

```
php artisan make:controller pathName/controllerName
```

This will create controller in app/Http/Controller/YourPath/Controller

To Create it in Some Other Directory You need to do as Follows Inside app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider

Give Your New Default path in $namespace

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
//to
protected $namespace = 'New Default Path'
```

If you keep $namespace Blank Then every time you create controller You will have to give the path

Try This. Hope it works

Comment: This Will Work You dont have to give entire Path just the folder name after the default path in which you have to create the controller

....Default path is app/Http/Controllers/

Comment: I have tried it like this `php artisan make:controller MyPath\MyController
` and this creates the MyPathMyController.php file in app\controllers folder

Comment: yes you'll be getting you Mycontroller inside the controller folder due to the default path

Comment: it should be `php artisan make:controller pathName/controllerName` with forward slash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129629/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-rohit-shah).

Comment: Its working ! @lewis4u and Rohit both of you thanks  a lot

Answer (score -1):

You only need to pass the name of the subdirectory like this:

php artisan make:controller subDriectory/YourController
php artisan make:controller subDriectory/YourController --plain

Please try it and see if it works :)

Comment: The "--plain" option does not exist.

Comment: It is not wroking